# Formatting database when using multiple criteria

Tags: postgresql

This should be a relatively simple question. I come from a Python background and don't do a lot of SQL stuff so thought I would ask this formatting question here.

Say I've got something that has

```
Criteria 1: True
Criteria 2: False
Criteria N: True
```

In Postgresql, is it better to set the database up as:

```
Column: Criteria
Row: [1:True,2:False,N:True]
```

or set each criteria as a column of its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three [Boolean columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-boolean.html):

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  criteria1 boolean,
  criteria2 boolean,
  criterian boolean
);
```

You can then formulate queries that involve these columns:

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE criteria1 = true
   AND criteria2 = false;
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE criteria1 = false
   OR criterian = true;
```

Relational databases are designed to do this. In addition, you can [create an index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-intro.html) on these columns.

Comment: Yea I understand the boolean columns, I was basically just saying should I do 1 column with a list in it that I parse through Python, or should I do multiple boolean columns. It seems you say multiple is correct, which is what I was thinking would be the correct and fastest way